# SQL first row by creation_date

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I need some help here if you please.
I always have difficulties getting the very first row from the table.

Each user might have multiple order_id and each order_id has his own date.
I need for each user to show only their first order_id and date, any suggestions?
Table example:

| User | order_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Andrew | 1242 | 2021-01-01 |
| Andrew | 1252 | 2021-01-03 |
| Mike | 1255 | 2021-01-04 |
| Andrew | 1256 | 2021-01-04 |
| John | 1266 | 2021-01-04 |
| Andrew | 1277 | 2021-01-06 |
| John | 1287 | 2021-01-06 |
| Johhny | 1288 | 2021-01-06 |

And I need to get the following:

| User | order_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Andrew | 1242 | 2021-01-01 |
| Mike | 1255 | 2021-01-04 |
| John | 1266 | 2021-01-04 |
| Johhny | 1288 | 2021-01-06 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT X.USER,X.ORDER_ID,X.DATE FROM 
 (
    SELECT C.USER,C.ORDER_ID,C.DATE,
       ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY C.USER ORDER BY C.date ASC)XCOL
      FROM YOUR_TABLE AS C
 )X WHERE X.XCOL=1
```

You can also use ROW_NUMBER()-based filtering

Comment: Great! It worked! I always have an issue with this "Row_Number" understanding and how to use it. Do you have any manuals that I could read through? Because googling is not helping, for some reason I'm trying to read it, and makes no sense at all...

Comment: Glad,it helps you. I am not sure if it completely works with PostgreSQL,but pretty good manual about using windows-functions is Itzik Ben-Gan's https://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-High-Performance-Functions-Developer-Reference/dp/0735658366/ref=sr_1_11?dchild=1&keywords=itzik+ben-gan&qid=1631264952&sr=8-11

Answer (score 1):

This is typically done using `distinct on ()` in Postgres:

```
select distinct on ("User") *
from the_table
order by "User", "date";
```

`distinct on()` returns only the first row per column passed in parentheses. The "first" is determined by the `order by` statement of the query.

More details can be found [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

Comment: distinct ON is not working, says that "ON" is an unknown function. And even when I've deleted "ON" it never filtered it.